# Sass/Bourbon .css output has errors with @font-face mixin

Tags: sass, mixins, bourbon

I'm using the default Sass/Bourbon mixin font-face.scss but the generated css is wrong, for some reason nesting the `body` tag under `@font-face`. I have no errors when it generates the CSS but the fonts aren't showing of course.

Any ideas?

CSS output:

```
@font-face {
    body {
        font-family: AgencyFB Regular;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url("../../fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular.eot");
        src: url("../../fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url("../../fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular.woff") format("woff"), 
         url("../../fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular.ttf") format("truetype"), 
         url("../../fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular.svg#AgencyFB Regular") format("svg"); 
    } 
}
```

SCSS:

```
body {
@include font-face(AgencyFB Regular, "fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular");  
font: $body-font-size;
line-height: $body-line-height;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting, but `@font-face { body {} }` is just as invalid as `body { @font-face {} }`.

Comment: where else can you put the `@include font-face` then? the outputted css should have a separate `@font-face` section and a `body` section that includes `font-family:AgencyFB Regular`, but it's nesting it.

Comment: Have you tried checking the related links? `--------------->` (hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254869/bourbons-font-face-mixin)

Answer (score 0):

Cimmanon's link pointed me in the right direction for a fix. Thanks!

Basically I moved the `@include font-face(AgencyFB Regular, "fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular");` outside of any css tag (ie: `body`).

Then included a `font-family: AgencyFB Regular` in the `body` tag.

Like this:

```
@include font-face(AgencyFB Regular, "fonts/agency/agencyfb_regular");

body {
    font-family: AgencyFB Regular;      
    font: $body-font-size;
    line-height: $body-line-height;
}
```